# Facebook tracking with utm tags results in 100 percent bouncerate for certain browsers

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, utm-parameters, facebook-ads-manager

I´ve experienced problems recently with the tracking of facebook ads. Solely traffic from Android Webview browser gets registered, all traffic from other browsers have a bouncerate of 100percent.

I also noticed that the traffic from the other browsers replace spaces in the utm_tag with +´s. As for android webview it remains the same. I fixed this but still all traffic from other browsers doesnt seem to be trackable.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Spaces are not legal URL characters.   They should be encoded in your URL parameters with `%20`.    Or just use underscores or dashes instead of spaces.   Are you using the Google Analytics URL builder to create your URLs so that you know they are properly formatted? https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/campaign-url-builder/

Comment: yes, fixed that, still facing the same problem with the traffic though... using live recordings with tag manager i noticed that the link shim referall gets sent to analytics... which seems really strange

Comment: "They should be encoded in your URL parameters with `%20`" - or `+` (in the query string).